# Uniform boundedness principle on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I can't prove following proposition:

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $L_n:H\to H$ be bounded, linear operators $(n=1,2,\cdots)$.

If, for all $x,y\in H$, a sequence $\{(L_nx,y)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, then a sequence $\{||L_n||\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded.

This proposition is similar to uniform boundedness principle, so I tried to prove in a same way, but I couldn't because I can't prove
\begin{equation}
H=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}X_m\hspace{10pt} \left(X_m=\{x\in H:\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, ||L_nx||\leq m\}\right)
\end{equation}
so Baire category theorem fails to be applied.

Is there any way to prove the above equation or completely different way to prove the main proposition?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Apply uniform boundedness twice. One application shows that $||T_nx||$ is bounded for every $x$ (that is, for every $x$ there exists $c_x$ such that $||T_nx||\le c_x$ for all $n$), and then another application shows that $||T_n||$ is bounded.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to David, I could prove the proposition.

For every $x\in H$, let $T_n:H\to\mathbb{R}$ be an operator such that

\begin{equation}
T_ny=(y,L_n x)
\end{equation}

Using the assumption on $L_n$ and uniform boundedness, we can deduce that a sequence  $||T_n||\subset\mathbb{R}$ is bounded.

Here, since $||T_n||=||L_nx||$, we have the conclusion, applying uniform boundedness again in an opposite way.